# How to match different properties in different locations within a list of JSON objects

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression, jayway

What is the JSON path Syntax needed to match different properties in different locations within a list of objects.

```json
[
  {
    "myObject": "obj1",
    "feilds": {
      "id": "123"
    },
    "other": {
      "otherId": "321"
    }
  },
  {
    "myObject": "obj2",
    "feilds": {
      "id": "234"
    },
    "other": {
      "otherId": "432"
    }
  },
  {
    "myObject": "obj3",
    "feilds": {
      "id": "345"
    },
    "other": {
      "otherId": "543"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to get following output by matching `id` and `otherId` both, of two objects and get the following outcome. I would prefer to give the absolute path for the two ID's like `feilds.id` and `other.otherId` if possible.

```json
[
  {
    "myObject": "obj1",
    "feilds": {
      "id": "123"
    },
    "other": {
      "otherId": "321"
    }
  },
  {
    "myObject": "obj3",
    "feilds": {
      "id": "345"
    },
    "other": {
      "otherId": "543"
    }
  }
]
```

Tried something like this, but didn't really give the result I'm expecting.

`$.[?((@.id=="123" && @.otherId=="321") || (@.id=="345" && @.otherId=="543"))]`